# Reading a single character from a file in python?

Tags: python, file-io

My question would be if there was any other way besides below to iterate through a file one character at a time?

```
with open(filename) as f:
  while True:
    c = f.read(1)
    if not c:
      print "End of file"
      break
    print "Read a character:", c
```

Since there is not a function to check whether there is something to read like in Java, what other methods are there. Also, in the example, what would be in the variable c when it did reach the end of the file? Thanks for anyones help.

Comment: Yes, it is "duplicate" code, but it is not the same question. If you actually bothered to read the other question, he got his answer, while I want to know of other ways as I have been trying. Thank you for point it out though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        for c in line:
            pass
```

Or what about this?

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for c in f.read():
        pass
```

Comment: +1. The first solution is generally better, as the latter might cause problems with very big files (running out of memory).

Comment: Ahh, I didn't think you could do that in a for loop in python (second code). Thanks.

Comment: @Lattyware: the same goes for the first because the file might contain very very long lines :P

Comment: @nightcracker True, but the odds are a lot lower.

Comment: Haha, you guys are great/ Thanks! By the way, what is pass?

Comment: @Andy: it's a dummy statement that means "nothing". It's used as a placeholder where normally a statement is required. And if my answer solved your question, consider marking it as accepted by ticking the tickbox to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
import itertools

with open("test.txt") as f:
    for c in itertools.chain.from_iterable(f):
        print(c)
```

`chain.from_iterable` makes an iterable that returns elements from the first iterable in the given iterable until it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted. Normally this is used to flatten out lists of lists, but in this case, it allows you to ignore the lines.

Whether this is really any better than nested loops is another matter (it'll be a little faster, but that's unlikely to matter), but worth mentioning.

Comment: But it doesn't make much sense to chain one iterable. Just use the file object itself in this case.

Comment: @Keith It does. They asker wanted characters, so the the file is an iterable of lines - which are strings, which are iterables. So this takes an iterable of lines and gives an iterable of characters.

Comment: Keith: you can see the file object as an iterable over iterables, because when iterated over it returns strings (which are iterable).

Comment: Does this read the entire file or an entire line into memory? Or does it read a buffer into memory? Thanks.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen It is lazy, the file will be loaded as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the other methods of file objects:

'close',
 'fileno',
 'flush',
 'isatty',
 'newlines',
 'next',
 'read',
 'readinto',
 'readline',
 'readlines',
 'seek',
 'softspace',
 'tell',
 'truncate',
 'write',
 'writelines',
 'xreadlines'

Which you can read about in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).

The variable `c` will be an empty string if there is nothing more to read. It evaluates as False, so the test `if not c` is True then. This indicates you are at the end of the file.

Comment: @nightcracker here are the questions: `what other methods are there. Also, in the example, what would be in the variable c when it did reach the end of the file?`

Comment: Fair enough, it sort-of answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate is to use a generator:

```
def blocks(infile, bufsize=1024):
    while True:
        try:
            data=infile.read(bufsize)
            if data:
                yield data
            else:
                break
        except IOError as (errno, strerror):
            print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
            break

f=open('somefile.txt','rb')

for c in blocks(f,1):
    print c
```

With a generator, the entire file is not held in memory and the underlying OS will usually perform adequate buffering of the disc reads.

As a generator, it will act like any other iterable; it will break when there are no more characters to read in the file.