# How do I print a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python at the moment and I'm resolving easy problems to get the feeling of it.

I'm trying to read a text file and print the maze that is inside of it:

```
##########
##---##--#
#--------#
#---###--#
#--------#
##-------#
##########
```

For now I have the following:

```
file = open("maze.txt", "r")
maze = file.readlines()
print(maze)

for i in range(len(maze)):
    for j in range(len()):
        print(maze[i][j])

file.close()
```

I want to be able to have acess to every single character inside the file, so my goal for now is to print it one by one. But I have no idea what to write inside the range of the second for loop.

I know it's kind of a dumb question, but I'm really stuck. Thank you!

Comment: You can't call `len()` with no argument.  Are you asking about the resultant error?  Or is the code you're running different from the code you posted?

Comment: FYI `file.close` should be `file.close()` but the better approach is to use a [context manager](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Comment: As long as you are learning python, you should get out of the habit of using `range()` in loops unless you really need to. Here you can just use `for line in file:` and then `for character in line:`. It saves a lot of indexing errors.

Comment: @Mark It prints nothing. Is it something wrong with my code? I'm using `print(maze[line][character])`

Comment: If you loop this way, you just `print(character)`. Or `print(character, end='')` if you don't want to print a new line with each call..

Comment: It still prints nothing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10422970/797495 - https://trinket.io/python3/0a76feae6b

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. In the second for loop you have the line `i`, so you should do `range(len(maze[i]))` in order to do `print(maze[i][j]`.

Comment: My bad, didn't pay close attention: `range(len(maze[i])`

Comment: And then `print(maze[i][j], end='')` rather than simply `print(maze[i][j])`. (You're missing the closing bracking for `print(maze[i][j])` incidentally.)

Comment: I tried it and it only prints the first element of each line

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some of the comments I was able to come to a solution

Instead of having

```
for i in range(len(maze)):
    for j in range(len()):
        print(maze[i][j])
```

I could replace it with this:

```
for line in maze:
    for char in line:
        print(char)
```

Thank you all!